# Extract record with both value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a query.

Result Set:

[image]

```
SELECT players.codsw,sessions.userid,sessions.idlocation,location.denomination
from sessions 
LEFT JOIN location ON location.idlocation = sessions.idlocation
LEFT JOIN players ON players.userid = sessions.userid
GROUP BY sessions.userid,sessions.idlocation
    HAVING players.codsw IN ('MEGA SHOW','ANCORINA')
ORDER BY location.denomination
```

I need to exctract only records with both `codsw`, in this case MEGA SHOW and ANCORINA and same `idlocation`.

If u see my resultset, it show all the `idlocation` with first or second `codsw` , not both.

I expect as the result to see for example only `idlocation` 34 or 623 and not the other.

Thanks a lot

Riccardo

Answer (score 0):

The subquery in the following query uses conditional aggregation to identifies desired groups containing both `MEGA SHOW` and `ANCORINA`.  This subquery is then inner joined to your original query to filter off records you don't want appearing in your result set.

```
SELECT players.codsw, sessions.userid, sessions.idlocation, location.denomination
FROM sessions 
LEFT JOIN location
    ON location.idlocation = sessions.idlocation
LEFT JOIN players
    ON players.userid = sessions.userid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sessions.userid AS userid, sessions.idlocation AS idlocation,
           SUM(CASE WHEN players.codsw IN ('MEGA SHOW', 'ANCORINA')
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS codswSum
    FROM sessions 
    LEFT JOIN location
        ON location.idlocation = sessions.idlocation
    LEFT JOIN players
        ON players.userid = sessions.userid
    GROUP BY sessions.userid, sessions.idlocation
    HAVING codswSum = 2
) t
    ON sessions.userid = t.userid AND sessions.idlocation = t.idlocation
ORDER BY location.denomination
```

Comment: Thank's Tim, but no change have effect, i have always single idlocation and single codsw like idlocation = 4058

Comment: This query implements your logic AFAIK.  If you can give specific feedback about what is not working, maybe I can help.

Comment: i have to extract all the location with both codesw MEGA SHOW and ANCORINA, the query actually extract  for example idlocation = 4058 where there is only MEGA SHOW record and not ANCORINA. If there are not MEGA SHOW AND ANCORINA i have not to exctract the record

Comment: Are you sure you actually tested my query?  Are you certain that `idlocation` 4058 doesn't have `codsw` `ANCORINA` ?

Comment: Yes Tim, the result is  only one records MEGA SHOW 18532 3729 Magazzino: MGZ Games Lodi Pordenone 2

Comment: @user2653710 I have updated my query now that I know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT players.codsw
      ,sessions.userid
      ,sessions.idlocation
      ,location.denomination
  FROM sessions sess
      ,location loc
      ,players  pl
 WHERE location.idlocation = sessions.idlocation
   AND players.userid = sessions.userid
   AND players.codsw IN ('MEGA SHOW', 'ANCORINA')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT sessions.idlocation
              ,COUNT(*)
          FROM sessions
              ,location
              ,players
         WHERE location.idlocation = sessions.idlocation
           AND players.userid = sessions.userid
           AND players.codsw IN ('MEGA SHOW', 'ANCORINA')
           AND sessions.idlocation = sess.idlocation
         GROUP BY sessions.idlocation
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
 ORDER BY location.denomination
```

Comment: yes, it take a lot of time to execute the query and resultset it's very big, but it's like what are my expectations